# Is this a bug in the Bash shell

Tags: bash, unix

Have I found a bug in bash?

1. I have created a folder named `Test`
2. cd Test/
3. rm -rf ../Test (Deleted the PWD while I was in that directory, as shown in image) [image: This picture show it]

Comment: What is the expected output of `ls`? After all you removed the directory. Also, `ls` is not part of bash.

Comment: I am not worried about `ls`. I am concerned about directory which is deleted

Comment: I wanted to answer that it's not a bug (I encounter such situations sometimes, so I think that it's a known behavior and if it has survived so many years, it's more a feature than a bug), but then I scratched my head trying to figure out what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Again, what do you expect? `../Test` points to a valid directory so of course you can delete it. Once you do that your `PWD` is invalid.

Comment: can you change directory with something like `cd $home/Darwin`? Then everything is ok.

Answer (score 5):

Not a bug, not related to bash either. You're current working directory (and all the environment variables that hold the path info in your shell) is simply pointing to a filesystem node that's been orphaned. Listing it will give you what's in the node, which is nothing because `.` and `..` are gone (because it's orphaned). Note that `rm` removes everything in the directory before orphaning the node. Thus, `ls` gives you nothing.

Also note that when you try to create a file while inside the deleted directory with something like `touch blah` or `mkdir blah`, it'll give you a file not found error.

"orphaned" may not be the correct term, I'm simply using it to mean that it has no parent node.